Email 2FA in OrderCloud
is there a provision to configure/enable email 2fa with ordercloud or should this be a custom solution only?
Regards,
Jacob Samuel
Such a option has not been tried previously in the project. looks like there are options to integrate with authenticator app but not with email. please assist.

Currently, 2FA is supported in OrderCloud if you implement OIDC, and your IDP supports email as an option for 2FA. Adding native support for MFA is on the roadmap for OrderCloud in the next year or so.
Source: Product Manager, OrderCloud.
